# Yahoo finance query api, want to limit to one country search result (Ionic cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic2, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

As we search a stock a ticker in Yahoo search, there will be search suggestion. Example, when I type 'TPM' in search, I only want Australia stocks which is TPM.AX or other Australia stocks appear in the stocks suggestion. I do not want to show other exchanges stocks tickers.

```
    cacheKey = ticker,
    stockDetailsCache = stockDetailsCacheService.get(cacheKey),

    query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN ("' + ticker + '")',
    url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIService.encode(query) + '.AX&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env';

    if(stockDetailsCache) {
      deferred.resolve(stockDetailsCache);
    }
    else {
      $http.get(url)
        .success(function(json) {
          var jsonData = json.query.results.quote;
          deferred.resolve(jsonData);
          stockDetailsCacheService.put(cacheKey, jsonData);
        })
        .error(function(error) {
          console.log("Details data error: " + error);
          deferred.reject();
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var getPriceData = function(ticker) {

    var deferred = $q.defer(),

    cacheKey = ticker,

    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/" + ticker + ".AX/quote?format=json&view=detail";

    $http.get(url)
      .success(function(json) {
        var jsonData = json.list.resources[0].resource.fields;
        stockPriceCacheService.put(cacheKey, jsonData);
        deferred.resolve(jsonData);
      })
```

I have put .AX in the url but still unable to shows Australia stocks for my app which is written in Ionic 2. Currently, all stocks from exchanges still shown.
How to make it only show Australia stocks in search suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN ("' + ticker + '")',
    url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIService.encode(query) + '+'.AX'+&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env';
```

Use +'AX'